# What does it really mean by reading file into memory all at once?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

I am confused with the term   "Do not read file into memory all at once". For the below code, will it be correct to say that I not reading file into memory all at once but line by line?

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.txt"); 
  
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
  
  String st; 
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(st); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether you read all at once or line by line, rather, it’s important whether you force the runtime to keep everything in memory. Since you are processing the lines one by one, without keeping them longer than necessary, you’ve not fallen for the discouraged anti-pattern. But mind that the advice is about avoiding to keep more in memory than needed, but if your task requires to have everything in memory, then it is the way it is…

Answer (score 2):

> For the below code, will it be correct to say that I not reading file into memory all at once but line by line?

You cannot make any such assumptions. Since you are using a *Buffered*Reader, all you can say with assuredness is that you are reading some of the file into a memory buffer, perhaps all of the file, but the buffer is in control, not you. And when the buffer's data has been depleted, then more of the file will be read into it, if there is still data remaining to be read.

Answer (score 0):

> For the below code, will it be correct to say that I not reading file into memory all at once but line by line?

Yes, this is correct. You are not falling into the anti-pattern of reading files into memory in this code.

Your code allows you to process arbitrarily large files using a small and bounded amount of memory, which is the point of the guideline.

Comment: Reading files into memory is not an anti-pattern. Doing so is perfectly fine if you are sure of your deployment scenario (number and size of files, amount of memory).

Comment: You probably agree that reading a file into memory to process it in a serial way is a common but bad initial approach. What would you call this if not an antipattern?